# How to write data to .csv file which user picked with file_uploader in Streamlit?

Tags: python, streamlit

I have a Web Application using Streamlit and I am using file_uploader to users can select which csv file they want to save data like the picture below.

[image: file_uploader]

I want to write data from AgGrid to the csv file selected by the user with the Streamlit file_uploader. But I am getting the error you see in the picture. How can I write data to the file using the object returned from the file_uploader function, I would be very grateful if you could help.

[image]

```
    import pandas as pd
    import streamlit as st

    file = st.file_uploader("Upload .csv file", type=FILE_TYPES)
    if file is not None:
      data = pd.read_csv(file)
      st.dataframe(data.head(10))

      dataframe = {
        "DateTime": ["ss"],
        "Name": ["s"],
        "Email": ["ese"],
        "Target User": ["csc"],
        "Alternate Target": ["dsd"],
        "Questions": ["ese"]
    }

      file.write(dataframe)
```

With the following line of code, I cannot write the dataframe I created to the csv file selected by the user with the file_uploader too.

```
dataframe.to_csv(file)
```

Comment: Is the space in the filename a typo?

Comment: I don't understand your point.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize an `if` statement for the uploaded file.

```py
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st


FILE_TYPES = ["csv"]

file = st.file_uploader("Upload .csv file", type=FILE_TYPES)
if file is not None:
    data = pd.read_csv(file)
    st.dataframe(data.head(10))
    
    dataframe = {
        "DateTime": ["ss"],
        "Name": ["s"],
        "Email": ["ese"],
        "Target User": ["csc"],
        "Alternate Target": ["dsd"],
        "Questions": ["ese"]
    }

    # Write the dataframe to a CSV file
    df = pd.DataFrame(dataframe)
    df.to_csv("dataframe.csv")

    # Write dataframe to streamlit 
    st.dataframe(df) 

    # Allow the user to download the new CSV file
    st.download_file(file, "dataframe.csv")
```

Comment: With this code, I got error like TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict'

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't completely understand your question. But to write dataframe to csv, use `df.to_csv(file_name)`

```
df = st.dataframe(data.head(10))
df.to_csv(<filename>)
```

Try this

Comment: I want to write df to the csv file which user picked with st file_uploader. I can get file name with file_uploader but I couldn't achieve to write df to file with this method too.

Comment: I tried your last lines but I got:  StreamlitAPIException: to_csv() is not a valid Streamlit command.